# Python: pandas dataframe interpolating to achieve equidistant time data points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been struggling for a while to make any progress on this task but basically I have setup a script which so far reads in text files containing multiple columns of data with the first column reading time as below:

```
    Time_(s)    Mass_Flow_(kg/s)   T_in_pipe(C)   T_in_water(C)   T_out_pipe(C)   T_out_water(C)
         0    1.2450   16.9029   16.8256   16.6234   16.6204
    2.8700    1.2450   16.8873   16.8094   16.6237   19.6507
    5.6600    1.2450   16.8889   16.8229   19.1406   29.1320
    8.7800    1.2450   16.8875   16.8236   24.1325   34.9077
   11.6200    1.2450   16.8794   16.8040   28.3927   38.5443
   16.0600    1.2450   16.8615   16.7942   33.7205   42.4149
   18.8900    1.2450   16.8512   16.7938   36.2797   44.1221
   23.0200    1.2450   16.8319   16.7903   39.2102   46.1857
```

Using pandas tool pd.read_csv, I have a dataframe containing each column with the titles included. I now want to resample this data such that the output dataframe contains all the data columns though at fixed time intervals specified by the user. For example, if the time step was chosen to be 10 seconds, the output using linear interpolation would be something as follows:

```
 Time_(s)   T_out_pipe(C)          T_out_water(C)          T_in_pipe(C)           T_in_water(C)           Mass_Flow(kg/s)
0   16.9028797149658    16.8256435394287    16.6234245300293    16.6203994750977    1.24500000476837
10  16.8840274810791    16.8151550292969    25.9625988006592    36.4699172973633    1.24500000476837
20  16.8460464477539    16.7928314208984    37.0673408508301    44.6767387390137    1.24500000476837
30  16.8223628997803    16.7767677307129    42.5221672058106    48.3903617858887    1.24500000476837
```

I've seen similar things being done using the resample function within pandas but all examples I've seen require the time data to be in the format of year/month/day/hour/minute/second. I am sure I could convert the first column to a time series as such but I feel in my case there must be a more simple method in doing so. If anybody else has worked with a similar conversion process I would be greatful for some insight.

Many thanks,

Keith

Answer (score 3):

`set_index` with `'Time_(s)'`, `reindex` + `interpolate`

```
d = df.set_index('Time_(s)')
t = d.index
r = pd.Index([0, 10, 20, 30], name=t.name)
df.set_index('Time_(s)') \
    .reindex(t.union(r)).interpolate('index').ix[r].reset_index()
```

[image]

---

***interpolation validation***

```
y0, y1 = 16.8875, 16.8794
x0, x1 = 8.78, 11.62

m = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)

f = lambda x: m * (x - x0) + y0

f(10)

16.88402042253521
```

---

***reference code***
exactly what I ran

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """Time_(s)    Mass_Flow_(kg/s)   T_in_pipe(C)   T_in_water(C)   T_out_pipe(C)   T_out_water(C)
     0    1.2450   16.9029   16.8256   16.6234   16.6204
2.8700    1.2450   16.8873   16.8094   16.6237   19.6507
5.6600    1.2450   16.8889   16.8229   19.1406   29.1320
8.7800    1.2450   16.8875   16.8236   24.1325   34.9077
11.6200    1.2450   16.8794   16.8040   28.3927   38.5443
16.0600    1.2450   16.8615   16.7942   33.7205   42.4149
18.8900    1.2450   16.8512   16.7938   36.2797   44.1221
23.0200    1.2450   16.8319   16.7903   39.2102   46.1857"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)

print(df)

d = df.set_index('Time_(s)')
t = d.index
r = pd.Index([0, 10, 20, 30], name=t.name)
df.set_index('Time_(s)') \
    .reindex(t.union(r)).interpolate('index').ix[r].reset_index()
```

Comment: Hey piRSquared,

Comment: This method doesn't seem to do much in my case. It returns a second dataframe d with the Index column being replaced by the values in Time_(s) from the original data frame. None of the other columns are affected. Just curious, did you run the same code you posted and got the output just like in the table above?

Comment: @KeithO'Donovan I updated my post with the exact code I ran.

Comment: I ran your exact code and still recieved the same output. It returns two dataframes:

Comment: First data frame d of size 8x5 with no time column but index values replaced by time points. Second data frame df is simply the original of size 8x6 with no values interpolated by the looks of things. Is there something I am missing out on here? Sorry if there is something obvious I am not doing - I'm quite new to Python!

Comment: @KeithO'Donovan the last command I'm running does not assign to `df`.  If you run `df` again, it will not be changed.  I did this on purpose.  I expected that you'd recognize this and assign it as needed.  `df = df.set_index('Time_(s)').reindex(t.union(r)).interpolate('index').ix[r].reset_index()` will accomplish the assignment.

Comment: @KeithO'Donovan I also, added an update to the post to validate the interpolation

Comment: Ok I see what you mean! At first glance I misread the last line to be an assignment statement. But this is exactly what I need so thanks a lot!